# Как отслеживать изменение размера окна

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть окно с текстовым полем и мне нужно получать ширину окна причём в реальном времени, что бы при изменении ширины или высоты, значения так же менялось что бы я мог менять размер виджета растягиванием окна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подстраивания размера виджета под размеры окна не обязательно отслеживать размеры окна и устанавливать размеры виджета вручную, это можно сделать средствами методов `pack` и `grid`.

Пример с pack:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Button").pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Кнопка будет подстраиваться под размер окна, при этом будет постоянный отступ от границ окна 10 пикселей.

Аналогично с помощью `grid`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Button").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Для колонки и строки, где размещен код устанавливается вес больше 0, из-за этого соответствующие колонки и строки расширяются до размера контейнера. Значение веса влияет на то, как будет растягиваться колонка или строка - чем больше вес, тем сильнее. Код немного сложнее, но настройки "веса" будет влиять на все виджеты, размещенные внутри соответствующих колонок и строк.

Теперь все то же самое, только через привязку к событию изменения размера окна и ручного размещения с помощью `place`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def config(event):
    if event.widget == root:
        button.place(x=10, y=10, width=event.width-20, height=event.height-20)


root.bind("<Configure>", config)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Button")

root.mainloop()
```